# Salty water impedance vs. frequency

Tags: electricity, capacitance, dielectric, electrochemistry

I was experimenting with measuring the dielectric constant of tap-water and also water with salt added.

The measurement was done by submerging a simple cylinder capacitor into a container with the water.

For frequencies up to about 1KHz the capacitor attenuates the signal as expected, but for higher frequencies it stops attenuating the signal.

I tried with pure water and here the attenuation continues into the MHz range as expected.

So there seems to be some frequency dependency happening with the salt. What are the theory describing the flow of ac current in salty water?

[image: Test Setup]

Comment: Consider adding a drawing (or two) of what your experimental setup is accompanied by some samples of your test results, otherwise it is very difficult to answer such a complex, pun intended, impedance question.

Comment: Salt solution is quite a good conductor (depending on the salt concentration) so you in effect have a resistor in parallel with your capacitor. It's hard to know exactly what effect this will have without more details of your circuit, but I would expect this to affect the low frequency behaviour rather than the high frequency behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to make a comment because I don't know the exact answer. But I don't have enough characters in a comment for what I want to say, so consider this more as a hint into the right direction than a full answer.

Obviously tap- and salt water are conductors. For charged systems, there is a relationship between conductivity and the dielectric function (since you have a conductor, the $\epsilon$ that is usually meant in electronics is infinite, because there is no DC-polarization. So here you have the dielectric function $\epsilon(\omega,q)$, where the dielectric constant is $\epsilon = \epsilon(0,0)$):

$$\epsilon(\omega,q) = 1+\frac{4\pi i}{\omega}\sigma(\omega,q),$$
where $q$ is the wavelength of the perturbation. I say perturbation, because this relationship above comes from linear response theory. So what you measure is a direct consequence of the frequency behaviour of the conductivity. Now, since electricity in water is carried by ions, in a homogenious solution, you should be able to apply Drude's theory of conductivity (here is where I'm out of depth, I'm only guessing). The conductivity in this model is given by

$$\sigma(\omega) = \frac{ne^2\tau}{m}\frac{1}{1-i\omega\tau},$$
where n is the charge carrier concentration. Maybe you can repeat your measurements with different salt concentrations, do a fit for $\tau$ and compare your value of $\tau$ to literature values.
EDIT: If not clear already, $\tau$ is the scattering time that gives rise to resistivity.

Comment: It is really strange, because the attenuation is about constant from 1kHz to above 1MHz. I updated the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent circuit model for an electrochemical cell is called the [Randles circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randles_circuit) and is necessary to understanding impedance measurements in aqueous solutions and is complicated..

[image]

> In electrochemistry, a Randles circuit is an equivalent electrical circuit that consists of an active electrolyte resistance RS in series with the parallel combination of the double-layer capacitance Cdl and an impedance (Zw) of a faradaic reaction. It is commonly used in electrochemical impedance spectroscopy (EIS) for interpretation of impedance spectra, often with a constant phase element (CPE) replacing the double layer capacity.

The double layer capacitance is a function of ion concentration while Zw is a function of the transfer rate of the electrons from ion to electrode.

The ions in solution are the charge carriers. This is why deionized water has the highest resistance (18 Meg ohm) and is closest to a dielectric material. Salt ions added to deionized water (in simple terms) create a leaky capacitor in your experimental setup.